# "Successful su for user by root" - suspicious entries in my /var/log/auth.log?

Tags: security, authentication, viruses, su, logs

[This post on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ydvz9/just_a_word_of_warning_the_latest_downloads_might/) made me go through my logs. That's when I discovered the following entries which appeared on two non-subsequent days. "user" is my user account.

```
Aug  4 22:50:37 UbuntuSystem sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by user(uid=1000)
Aug  4 22:50:39 UbuntuSystem sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug  4 22:51:16 UbuntuSystem su[10710]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:16 UbuntuSystem su[10710]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:16 UbuntuSystem su[10710]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10710]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10720]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10720]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10720]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10720]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10735]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10735]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10735]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10735]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10763]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10763]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10763]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10763]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10773]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10773]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10773]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10773]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10788]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10788]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10788]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10788]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10801]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10801]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10801]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10801]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10814]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10814]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10814]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10814]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10829]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10829]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10829]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10829]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10842]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10842]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10842]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10842]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10855]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10855]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10855]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 22:51:17 UbuntuSystem su[10855]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11153]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11153]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11153]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11153]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11166]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11166]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11166]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11166]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11181]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11181]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11181]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11181]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11193]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11193]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11193]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11193]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11211]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11211]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11211]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11211]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11226]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11226]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11226]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11226]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11241]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11241]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11241]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11241]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11253]: Successful su for user by root
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11253]: + ??? root:user
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11253]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug  4 23:41:39 UbuntuSystem su[11253]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug  4 23:42:18 UbuntuSystem gnome-screensaver-dialog: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Aug  4 23:42:33 UbuntuSystem polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 (system bus name :1.48, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)

Aug 15 20:17:01 UbuntuSystem CRON[26579]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 15 20:17:01 UbuntuSystem CRON[26579]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 15 21:15:15 UbuntuSystem su[27098]: Successful su for user by root
Aug 15 21:15:15 UbuntuSystem su[27098]: + ??? root:user
Aug 15 21:15:15 UbuntuSystem su[27098]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug 15 21:15:15 UbuntuSystem su[27098]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug 15 21:17:01 UbuntuSystem CRON[27141]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 15 21:17:01 UbuntuSystem CRON[27141]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Apart from these iterations the only other times I found a similar output was when trying out the guest account:

```
Aug 11 22:38:49 UbuntuSystem lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user lightdm
Aug 11 22:38:49 UbuntuSystem groupadd[2918]: group added to /etc/group: name=guest-4Eflre, GID=125
Aug 11 22:38:49 UbuntuSystem groupadd[2918]: group added to /etc/gshadow: name=guest-4Eflre
Aug 11 22:38:49 UbuntuSystem groupadd[2918]: new group: name=guest-4Eflre, GID=125
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem useradd[2922]: new user: name=guest-4Eflre, UID=115, GID=125, home=/, shell=/bin/bash
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem usermod[2927]: change user 'guest-4Eflre' password
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem chage[2932]: changed password expiry for guest-4Eflre
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem chfn[2935]: changed user 'guest-4Eflre' information
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem usermod[2943]: change user 'guest-4Eflre' home from '/' to '/tmp/guest-4Eflre'
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem su[2948]: Successful su for guest-4Eflre by root
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem su[2948]: + ??? root:guest-4Eflre
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem su[2948]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user guest-4Eflre by (uid=0)
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem su[2948]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user guest-4Eflre
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user guest-4Eflre by (uid=0)
Aug 11 22:38:50 UbuntuSystem lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm-autologin:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
```

I might have to add that I set up my system only fairly recently (Aug 4).

Is this behaviour normal? What exactly is going on with all the su commands? Do I have to be worried that my system might be compromised?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those warnings are when you switch from root to your user.

It doesn't appear that you have any problem.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply! I sincerely hope that's the case. However, in general I issue at least one sudo command (mostly apt-get update&upgrade) per session. Do you have any idea why these entries only appeared on two days total?

Comment: It could be some scheduled jobs or one version of sudo that had that issue.

Comment: Alright, thanks again. I am relieved for now. Sill, I'll make sure to monitor the logs over the next days to see if those entries reappear and try to find out what's causing them. I'll edit my OP if I find anything.

Answer (score 7):

These are **not** from when you run `sudo`. But they are not a problem, either.

The messages say:

```
Successful su for user by root
```

*This happens whenever you log in.* Whether you're logging in as a real user or as a guest user, the *login screen runs as `root`*, so it must change user identity *from* `root` *to* a non-`root` user as part of the login process.

This isn't **`user`** becoming `root`. This is `root` becoming **`user`**.

Comment: I see, thanks! Do you know if there's any reason as to why these entries only appeared on two out of countless logins, though?

Comment: @Glutanimate That's a good point. While this is root becoming you (and not you becoming root), *there's something wrong with my assumption that this is you logging on*. On a 12.04 system configured normally, a login actually looks different from this. For example, on my 12.04 system it looks like `Aug 17 17:09:37 Del lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user ek by (uid=0)`. I wonder if you have scheduled tasks running as your user. (*Some* such tasks can be revealed by running `crontab -l`.)

Comment: Ultimately, something is going on that I cannot (presently) explain. I don't think it's cause for concern, but it's worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found at least one of the culprits:

```
Aug 21 16:15:09 UbuntuSystem su[30135]: Successful su for user by root
Aug 21 16:15:09 UbuntuSystem su[30135]: + ??? root:user
Aug 21 16:15:09 UbuntuSystem su[30135]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug 21 16:15:09 UbuntuSystem su[30135]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug 21 16:15:09 UbuntuSystem sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 21 16:15:12 UbuntuSystem sudo:      user : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/cpu-control high
Aug 21 16:15:12 UbuntuSystem sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Aug 21 16:15:12 UbuntuSystem su[30174]: Successful su for user by root
Aug 21 16:15:12 UbuntuSystem su[30174]: + ??? root:user
Aug 21 16:15:12 UbuntuSystem su[30174]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Aug 21 16:15:12 UbuntuSystem su[30174]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user
Aug 21 16:15:12 UbuntuSystem sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

In this case the entries were connected to Jupiter power applet and specifically appeared when changing the CPU power mode. As there was no mention of Jupiter in any of the other instances, I cannot be sure whether they can be attributed to the same process.

I will keep monitoring my logs and post any further results here.